# Given $g(x,y)$ with continous and differnatiable derivations for all $(x,y)$ points

Tags: calculus

Given $g(x,y)$ with continous and differnatiable derivations for all $(x,y)$ points(I mean by that: $f'_x$ has a value, continous and differantiable, same for $f'_y$), and given $g'_x(0,0) = 1 , g'_y(0,0) = 2$

How do I compute this monster?! (Question from exam, with no solution..)
[image]

Answer is : $\frac{5}{\sqrt5}$

Comment: By f, do you mean g?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution, found it :)
[image]

Comment: Please consider writing this as text (and [formatting](https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help) it) instead of an image.

Comment: I suspect the exam problem was intended to test your understanding of directional derivatives vs. partial derivatives.  Your handwritten solution could be improved upon to better highlight the relationship.